# How to bind external api values to an angular interface and show it in a component (html)?

Tags: angular, api

I have been searching and searching, but no definitive answer. So I'll try it this way. It's actually very simple but I just don't know how to implement it (new to angular but know the basics).

I want a component that shows the current price of an asset. I have this api call that returns JSON.
Api call: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd
Returns: [image]

But here's the thing. How do I bind this data to an interface in angular? I only need the usd price value to show in the component, but need to bind it to a class first so I can use it in the html component.

What values does the class need to have? This didn't work:
[image]

Maybe someone knows a nice api tutorial that shows how to do this? I haven't found any as of yet. Also the ones I found have definitive attributes defined in the response like: {
"Name": bitcoin
"usd": 10279.66
}

In short: Fetch data from that API (just the price). And use it in the template (angular component.html)

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve fetching data from API and showing in template?

Comment: Yep exactly that, I want to fetch that data from that API (the price in usd) and show it in the template (angular component).

Comment: Lemme add a solution hold on.

Comment: Would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read data from API you need to create an Angular [Service](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

**NOTE:** Http GET return Observable which we subscribe to read data, and we must need to unsubscribe observable to prevent memory leak, there are several ways to [unsubscribe observable](https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-ways-to-unsubscribe-from-observables-in-angular-ab912819a78f) I used [ngrx take(1)](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/take) operator to unsubscribe.

**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

export interface IcoindDetail {
 bitcoin?: { usd: number },
 ethereum?: { usd: number }
}

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyService {

// inject httpClient to read restful methods
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} 

// create a method that read API URL using GET method
getData() {
  const url = 'https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd';

  // return API response
  return this.http.get<IcoindDetail>(url)
 }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
data: IcoindDetail;

// inject service to read methods
constructor(private service: MyService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  // read response from API and store in data variable
  this.service.getData()
    .pipe(take(1)) // notice take(1) to unsubscribe observable  
    .subscribe((res) => this.data = res)
}
```

**template.html**

```
<div *ngIf="data"> {{ data.bitcoin.usd }} </div>
```

Working [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ucp6gu)

Comment: Awesome, this works! Is there a way though where I can have 1 class and use it for all kind of responses and not just bitcoin,usd. But also ethereum,usd etc?

Comment: yeah, you can add more methods in that service which serves different purpose.

Comment: Ah ok, but for the IcoinDetail interface I need to create new ones that are like IcoinDetail2 {ethereum: {usd: number}}? Or is there an easier way.

Comment: No need for that you can add in same IcoinDetails with optional value by suing question mark I have updated my answer checkout interface now it contains both value with optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `service` to get the `API` response and then inject your service in any component that you want (Dependency Injection). Set the local variable of your component with the return value from service.

So try something like this:

**app.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  const apiUrl = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price? 
                        ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd"

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  
  getApiRespons(): Observable()<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl);
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './app.srvice';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public obj:any = {};
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.apiService.getApiRespons().pipe(take(1)).subscribe(
     res => {
       this.obj = res;
     }
   );
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>{{ obj.bitcoin.usd }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where `this.res` is being used? it will always have `undefined` value coz you are subscribing observable not returning.

Comment: It was Misspelling mistake ;). I revised it for you!

Comment: You are subscribing Observable which must need to unsubscribe to prevent memory leak, looks like that part is missing from your answer.

Comment: Ok, I revised it. Thank you